# Program terminating before running?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class GSM extends Canvas implements Runnable {

//The game state manager

public final long secondNS = 1000000000;
public final long frameNS = secondNS/60;
public boolean running = true;
public long now = System.nanoTime();
public long startTime = now;
public long lastFrame = now;
public long lastSecond = now;
public int frames = 0;

public void run() 
{

    System.out.println("Program started.");
    while(running)
    {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        if(now - lastFrame >= frameNS)
        {
            lastFrame = now;
            frames++;
        }
        if(now - lastSecond >= secondNS)
        {
            lastSecond = now;
            System.out.println(frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new GSM();
}
}
```

Just starting to make a game engine but the program terminates right away. Can someone point out the error? I know there's something missing that will be super obvious and I'm going to facepalm, i appreciate your helps. Thank you!

Comment: You really need to start by learning basics. Even a simple game engine is a complex piece of software, and you don't have the expertise yet. Start with simpler projects and work your way up.

Comment: You do realize that even if you create a `Thread` to run your `Runnable`, it isn't going to show any GUI on the screen just because it's a `Canvas`, right? Also, you're busy-waiting in your `while` loop, which is a bad thing.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run a `Runnable`, you have to start it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Thread(new GSM()).start();
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score 1):

GSM implements Runnable, but you're not actually creating a thread for it to run in, hence the run() method is never called

Comment: Paul's answer had the example - `new Thread(new GSM()).start();`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new GSM but you never call run. I assume you're trying to start a thread but that requires that you use a Runnable and a Thread object. If that is what you want to do [Oracle has a tutorial on it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html).